# WiX Installer with many subfolders and files

Tags: c#, .net, wix

I am trying to make an installer of my .net project using the WiX toolset. My project needs a bunch of javascript files with a specific folder structure, that are copied to the Release folder with a post build event after compiling the solution. I have read that all the files should be explicitly written in the WiX file, but there are thousands of files inside the JS folder.

I have thought three different solutions, but I am not sure which one is better or if there is a better approach:

1. In a post build event of the project, call a script that make a .zip of the folder containing the JS files, add only one line to the WiX project in order to only copy that file and finally on the start of the program unzip de JS folder and remove the zip (that will be done only the first time). The problem is that the first execution of the program will need administrator rights.
2. Create a new exe to extract the zip and launch it in a CustomAction of the MSI generated by the WiX toolset. The problem is that if because of some reason this step is not executed the software will not be able to start never, in contrast with the previous approach where the software itself check every time it starts the existence of the zip.
3. Create a complex script that fills the WiX file with each of the JS file and each of the subfolders and trigger it in a post build event.

Anyone can give another option or tell me which one I should use?

Comment: the answer here might help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42278203/wix-toolset-include-multiple-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add your files to WiX, you need to use `heat.exe` utility (http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html)

Here is the sample I used in PowerShell

```
& "$env:WIX\bin\heat.exe" dir $sourceDir -ag -dr INSTALLDIR -srd -sfrag -suid -cg ProductComponents -out ProductComponents.wxs
```

Comment: This is the right answer, because it also eliminates the drag of removing the files again at uninstallation, and works for repairs as well. You'll need a lot of code and complexity for option 1 and 2.